# Clear canvas before Multiple Objects Render on Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I have multiple objects rendered on Canvas, each listening to keydown for directional movement, and redrawing using [requestAnimationFrame](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/).

Problem is, if I set the clear canvas on each of the object's redraw, there will be more than one clear canvas function running in btw different object's redraws, causing the objects to flicker. What is the best way to go about redrawing (and clearing) multiple objects on canvas.

```
function CreatePawn() {             
            var x = 25,
                y = 25;

            animate();

            function draw() {               
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cwidth, cheight);
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.lineWidth="3";
                ctx.arc(x, y, 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // circle               
                ctx.stroke();               
            };

            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                if(left) x -= speed;
                if(up) y -= speed;
                if(right) x += speed;
                if(down) y += speed;
                draw();
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to have 1 global setInterval (time loop) running which would clear canvas first, then loop-redraw all the objects that were pushed into an array.

Each object could still have their internal time loop to check for x/y changes, but the redrawing was up to the global setInterval.

Comment: If by _"redrawing was up to the global setInterval"_ you mean that it looped through the array of active objects and called `myObject.draw()`, then this is what I was suggesting. I'm sorry that you did not find it clear, but thank you for providing the reason that you downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I recognised that function...

The underlying problem is that the canvas for your board should not be part of the `Pawn` object, but part of an all-encompassing `Board` object.

It's then *that* object which should handle the animation events, clearing itself and then invoking each pawn's `draw()` method, to which it should pass the appropriate context.